# How to know the minimum deployment target a pod needs?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I'm using [`firebase_app_check`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_app_check) in my app and when I run

```
pod install
```

It gives me an error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/AppCheck":
> In Podfile:
> firebase_app_check (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_app_check/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.6-4, which depends on
> Firebase/AppCheck (~> 8.10.0)
>
> Specs satisfying the `Firebase/AppCheck (~> 8.10.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I have the following in my `Podfile`

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

and as I read the `firebase_app_check.podspec.json` file, it mentions the deployment target must be `9.0` or greater:

```
"platforms": {
  "ios": "9.0"
}
```

But if I increase the minimum deployment target to `11.0`, it works. So, where and how can I know what's the minimum deployment target a dependency need?

Comment: Minimum deployment targets are usually mentioned in readme files where the framework or library is hosted.
That's the sign of a well-maintained Framework/Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the published podspec to see the definitive version. For example, you can see that version 8.10.0 of Firebase/AppCheck requires iOS 11.0 [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.10.0/Firebase.podspec.json#L172).

For Firebase/AppCheck in particular, the podspec has been updated [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/9187) to support installation back to iOS 9 and that update will release with 8.11.0 next week.